# Ng-class removing class when click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-class

I have a button on main page that link to some another page. When that button clicked I want to remove class from one div.

Controller:

```
$scope.myClass = ["container","gnc1"];
     $scope.removeClass = function() {
     $scope.myClass.splice(1, 2);
}
```

I am using ui-router for this:

```
<body ui-view="viewA">
    <div ng-class="myClass">
    <div ui-view="viewC">
    <div ui-view="viewB">

        <a ui-sref="B"> </a> //Loads the B.html to where viewB is. ControllerB


        <a ui-sref="C" ng-click="removeClass()"> </a> //Loads the C.html where viewC is. controllerC


  </div>

  </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Button:

```
<a ng-click="removeClass()"></a>
```

What am I missing here? How can I remove that "gnc1" class?

**Edit-1:**

```
<div ng-class="{container:dogru, gnc1:yanlis}">
```

indexCtrl:

```
$scope.dogru = true;
$scope.yanlis = true;
```

Button belongs to controllerC so in controllerC:

```
$scope.removeClass = function($scope) {
        $scope.dogru = true;
        $scope.yanlis = false;
    }
```

But this didnt work either. What am i missing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jae7odee/2/ - looks just fine

Comment: @Arun P Johny Ahh sorry, click evet trigger some other things too I forgot it. Controller changes when that button clicked. I am gonna update my question.

Comment: update and share the fiddle to recreate your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `ng-class` like this instead

```
<div ng-class="{container:isConditionTruthy, gnc1:!isConditionTruthy}">

...ng-click="isConditionTruthy = !isConditionTruthy"...
```

If you post a fiddle with your code I can show you.

Comment: Its too complicated too create jsfiddle. Could you show me simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Just pop the element out, since the item you want to remove is at the end of the array.

```
myClass = ["container","gnc1"];

removeLast = function() {
     myClass.pop();
}
removeLast();
console.log(myClass);
```